# LSTM on top of CNN

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have the following lstm model implementation in torch, which I took from here:
https://github.com/wojzaremba/lstm/blob/master/main.lua

I have a question about the following piece of code:

```
local function create_network()
  local x                = nn.Identity()()
  local y                = nn.Identity()()
  local prev_s           = nn.Identity()()
  local i                = {[0] = LookupTable(params.vocab_size,
                                                    params.rnn_size)(x)}
  local next_s           = {}
  local split         = {prev_s:split(2 * params.layers)}
  for layer_idx = 1, params.layers do
    local prev_c         = split[2 * layer_idx - 1]
    local prev_h         = split[2 * layer_idx]
    local dropped        = nn.Dropout(params.dropout)(i[layer_idx - 1])
    local next_c, next_h = lstm(dropped, prev_c, prev_h)
    table.insert(next_s, next_c)
    table.insert(next_s, next_h)
    i[layer_idx] = next_h
  end
  local h2y              = nn.Linear(params.rnn_size, params.vocab_size)
  local dropped          = nn.Dropout(params.dropout)(i[params.layers])
  local pred             = nn.LogSoftMax()(h2y(dropped))
  local err              = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()({pred, y})
  local module           = nn.gModule({x, y, prev_s},
                                      {err, nn.Identity()(next_s)})
  module:getParameters():uniform(-params.init_weight, params.init_weight)
  return transfer_data(module)
end
```

In the embedding part of the lstm input, the code uses a `LookupTable` layer when handling the ptb data base, now I'm wondering how to use `LookupTable` to define other embedding to different type of data. Specially, the input is RGB images and the embedding will be one of the CNN models e.g AlexNet without fully connected layers. ( https://gist.github.com/gcr/0bab9929dfee95164a4d )

Its's looks too fuzzy for me. 
There is a better design for this purpose?
How can I create LSTM on top of CNN model?

Answer (score 0):

Torch nn.LookupTable is simply [doing](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/LookupTable.lua#L75) Tensor [index](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-indexdim-index) on its weight Tensor. In the code you specified it is also used to learn word vectors, since it is included in the nngraph model. If you have a pre-trained model, you can set it's weights to LookupTable, but this time, you shouldn't include it in the nngraph. The dimensions of weight tensor shoud be nIndex (e.g. how many different images you have) x nOutput (e.g. the LSTM hidden size - rnn_size in your code).  Or, you don't have to use LookupTable at all, you can specify the input Tensor directly.